# React Module not found: Can't resolve '../utils/api'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, require, importerror

I created a module in which I keep functions to call an api. While 'requiring' it, I get the following error:

```
./src/Components/Search/SearchPage.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '../utils/api' in 'C:\Users\riksch\Dropbox\projects\Current\greenmp\frontend\src\Components\Search'
```

**My main question is: how do I correctly import the api module into SearchPage.js?**

**Here is the structure of my project:**

[image]

I've highlighted the files that I use, 1 is the file that I import (require) from, and 2 is the module I try to import.

This worked before, but now that I changed the folder structure, even after adjusting the path, I can't get it too work.

I've tried different import paths, all with the same error.

**SearchPage.js require statement**

```
const api = require('../utils/api')
```

**api.js**

```
var axios = require('axios')


module.exports = {
  retrievePlants: function(search_query, locale) {
    console.log("api.retrievePlants executes")
    console.log("url: " + 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/'+locale+'/'+search_query)
    //FIXME: hardcoded URL HOST
    // return axios.get('https://127.0.0.1/search/'+locale+'/'+search_query)
    return axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/'+locale+'/'+search_query)
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log("response.data:")
        console.log(response.data)
        return response.data
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log("Error in Components.utils.api.retrievePlants:")
        console.log(error)
        console.log("console.log(error.response.data):")
        console.log(error.response.data)
      })
  },
}
```

Comment: You need go up two directories. `../` (Out of search dir) and `'../` (Out of Components)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to go two directories up like below

```
const api = require('../../utils/api');
```

it will work.

Comment: So, looking at your answer and that of brandNew, '../' just gets me out of the search dir (into the Components dir), and then '../' gets me another directory higher. That helps me to understand this, thanks!